# How to stop the program once a return value of None is recieved?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

my problem is my code has this structure: as you can see the second function depends on the outcome of the first. but I want the program to end when the first function catches an error but what I get is, it displays the exception message of the first function and it proceeds to the next step of the main function by assuming the first function gave it a None value which causes a Type error which I don't want. what should I do?
PS: assume that i have 40 functions which depend up on each other like the ones below upto 'func50'

```
def func1(input1):
    try:
        table = []
        #some stuffs here which append to table       
        return table
    except IOError:
        print("try again")
def func2(formatted_file):
    try:
        val = {}
        #some stuffs here
        return val
    except IndexError:
        print("index error")
def main():
    input1 = input("insert val")
    formatted_file = func1(input1)
    mine = funct2(formatted_file)
    print(mine)
main()
```

Comment: *Don't* catch errors to let them propagate upwards…?!

Comment: can you please explain further? i need to use errors because my professor said try-catch usage is part of his final exam critical points and told us to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in your except block to stop the code from progressing, otherwise the `print()` is the only action in case of the `try:` not working.

Comment: Note that this is pretty bad practice in reality: any error would immediately kill your program, which is Very Bad in large programs. You should simply catch exceptions *at an appropriate level* when you have a plan what to do with it. Don't catch exceptions too early and then pretend nothing happened, but also don't not catch them at all, because that makes your program crash with a nasty message.

Comment: yeah, my professor strongly advised against it as well

Comment: @deceze what if I put my lines in the main function inside try block and finally an exception block saying "thanks for using our platform"?

Comment: I just answered the question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no IOError. The list remains empty. The given code is an edited version of your code. Change try-except to if table is empty set and rasies a system exit if condition is true

````
def func1(input1):
        table = []

        #some stuffs here which append to table
        if table == []:
            print('try again')
            raise SystemExit(0)
        return table

def func2(formatted_file):
    try:
        val = {}
        #some stuffs here
        return val
    except IndexError:
        print("index error")
def main():
    input1 = input("insert val")
    formatted_file = func1(input1)
    mine = func2(formatted_file)
    print(mine)
main()```
````

Comment: what if I put my lines in the main function inside try block and finally an exception block saying "thanks for using our platform"?

Comment: If you consider the case where i have 40 different functions depending on one another using if statement inside all of them again would not be preferable.

Comment: do you want to use an seperate try block or of one of the 2 functions

Comment: you can create a common function with a list parameter and run it inside the function

Comment: Not much. it will print the exception error message